# Show method name in "Find all references" - C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

When i rightclick something in visual studio and press *Find all references* i get a list of all locations where this object occur.

Is there any way to also show the scope of this location (Namespace.Class.Method) instead of just a line-number. Now i have to doubleclick all of the results to see where it actually is.

Answer (score 1):

One more vote for [ReSharper](http://download.jetbrains.com/resharper/ReSharperSetup.4.5.1274.1.msi).  Check [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html#Find_Usages) for some screenshots as to the type of results.  You can change how the results are presented (My favourite is Project+Namespace+Member, so I can see which methods the references are coming from.)

You also have a few options to refine your searches.  For example:

- Search project / file or even include referenced libraries
- Search for Read or Write usages
- Search for "text" matches

They have a free trial available... try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, for this you'll need a productivity tool, like Reshaper. (Other productivity tools, such as DevExpress, do exist, however I don't know if they also provide such a feature.)

Answer (score 0):

Using the default feature in Visual Studio, you can't achieve that. The `Find All References` seems to use the same search engine as the `Find In File`.

As M.Chohan said, a plugin like Reshaper or DevExpress CodeRush might have the feature you are seeking.

Comment: It does search in the correct scope so i think it's a bit more advanced than Find in file, for example you can Find all references of "i" in a for-loop and not find all loops in the entire file. But i'm also afraid it's not possible to exploit this advancyness without plugins.

Comment: @Pierre: Find All References is *completely* different from Find in Files. The algorithms are fully disjoint.